# register different events on multiple layers using Openlayers

Tags: events, openlayers

I have a problem with Openlayers events:

I want to register the drag event for a marker layer and also a hover event for a route layer. But it seems that the map only reacts to the event on the layer with the highest z-index. Is there a solution for this so that the two different event listeners can work at the same time?

Here is the relevant codes:

```
this.theMap = new OpenLayers.Map("map", options);
this.theMap.addLayer(waypointsLayer,routeSegmentLayer);
var dragControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(waypointsLayer, {
'onComplete': function(feature, pixel){
    self.emit('map:markerAdded', feature);
}           
});
this.theMap.addControl(dragControl);
dragControl.activate();
var selectRouteSegment = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
routeSegmentLayer,
{
    multiple: true,
    hover: true,
    onSelect: f_select,
    onUnselect: f_unselect
});
this.theMap.addControl(selectRouteSegment);
selectRouteSegment.activate();
```

Comment: What does your source look like where you bind the function to the event?  OpenLayers is definitely capable of what you are describing at any rate.

Comment: hi, i've just added the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SelectFeature` control to handle hovering over routes, try to set `stopDown` attribute to `false` to allow propagate `mousedown` events to underlying layers, as in example

```js
var selector = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(routeLayer, {
    hover: true,
    autoActivate: true
});
selector.handlers.feature.stopDown = false;
```

I am using this code to drag whole map while clicking *within* feature (otherwise drag doesn't work).

See more at [OpenLayers.Handler.Feature.stopDown](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Handler/Feature-js.html#OpenLayers.Handler.Feature.stopDown) and other corresponding properties.

Also you can get some clues from this code (I didn't try it myself but at first look it seems useful ;):
http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2010-May/017688.html

Comment: thanks for the tip, i've tried it out, but it doesn't work in my case, might be useful in the future.